# Shard and rebalance via CLI

Tags: nosql, rethinkdb

Is it possible to rebalance shards via rethinkDb command-line?

I tried to do it but all data remains in one of the shards. In web interface I can rebalance automatically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[This  screencast](http://youtu.be/cnpSi9qI02E?t=8m48s) (starting from 8:48) explains how to set up a cluster with a mix of command line and web interface.

In the documentation: [Sharding and replication](http://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/sharding-and-replication/) (section: Sharding via the command-line interface) there is some explanation on how to set up split points.

Unfortunately there is little documentation to do so specific things right now.

Comment: yes I've seen the screencast but it doesnt explain how to rebalance from cli. Btw thx a lot for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can shard with the CLI, but this is done by manually setting split points (and not by setting the number of shards)

The syntax is

```
split shard <TABLE> <SPLIT-POINT>
```

The web interface infers what good split points are based on the distribution of keys. The CLI currently doesn't do it.

Comment: yes but the point is how to rebalance from cli. Is it possible? thx a lot.

Comment: Yes you can, but it's incredibly painful to do.
You basically have to remove the old split points and manually recreate better ones.
Hash shards should fix this issue but it's currently not available -- https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/364

Comment: On second thoughts, no you cannot balance (or rebalance) anything with the CLI because you cannot retrieve the distributions of the keys.